# How to get QScreen before the QApplication is executed

Tags: qt, x11

I'm looking for a solution to read some informations about my physical display before I inialize my QApplication. I'm working on a ubuntu machine with Qt 5.8 and want to get informations about the inch size of the display and the display resolution.
 Any ideas? Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I allready testet this:

1. creating a `QApplication`
2. read the primary `QScreen`
3. quit and delete the QApplication
4. doing stuff with qscreen
5. create the main application that contains a QWebEngine << crash

Problem with this solution is near the initalization of `QtWebEngine`. It breaks with a segmentation fault at `QWebEngineProfile::defaultProfile()`

Comment: Can you explain *why* this needs to be done before you initialize your `QApplication` instance?  This sounds like an X-Y problem, where the solution may lie elsewhere.  Also, you'll get better answers if you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You do not need to do anything like that. Create the `QApplication` and keep it around until you exit your program. That's how it's meant to be used, and that's the only kind of use it supports. Otherwise, please expose why you think you need to go through your proposed machinations: most likely, it stems from a misunderstanding of some sort.

Answer (score 3):

[QDesktopWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html) can be used to get screen information.

[You can't get screen information before **QApplication** was created in your application.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopwidget.html#obtaining-a-desktop-widget)

As workaround, you can create separate project for small utility (it can print out screen parameters to console or write them into **QSettings**, for example), which you will launch before **QApplication** initialization from your main application.

Comment: Thank you, the approach with the QSettings is good, an inline solution would be nicer but at least I'm failed